# Angular 7 - Lazy loading with nested material tabs

Tags: angular, angular-material, lazy-loading

In my angular-7 project, I am trying to make an html page with nested material tabs where in second tab will have another set of tabs. In second tab, trying to make canvas chart for data passed to child component.

Here is my html code.

```
<mat-tab-group mat-stretch-tabs [selectedIndex]="0">
    <mat-tab label="Sales"> Sales            
    </mat-tab>

    <mat-tab label="Purchase">
        <!-- <ng-template matTabContent>               //This block works but i want in tab format
            <div *ngIf="isReady " class="divinput ">
                <div *ngFor="let d of data">
                    <draw [input]="d "></draw>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ng-template> -->

        <mat-tab-group *ngIf="isReady">                   // this throws error
            <mat-tab *ngIf="isReady" label="north">
                <ng-template matTabContent>
                    <div *ngFor="let d of data">
                        <draw [input]="d"></draw>
                    </div>
                </ng-template>
            </mat-tab>
        </mat-tab-group>

    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

The above code calls a child component "draw" which has function to draw chart.

```
private draw (chart){ 
    var canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement> document.getElementById(chart.id);
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    return new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {labels: chart.x,datasets: mydata}
    }) 
}
```

this throws error , `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null` for line `var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");` in function draw. It looks like material-tabs does not wait for data to be available. I tried to handle this by "isReady" but no luck.

One strange thing i noticed that, it works when I change `[selectedIndex]="0"` to `[selectedIndex]="1"` . But can not consider this as first tab should be active on load as per requirement.

I struggling hard to figure out the problem. Please help to resolve the issue.

Comment: did you call `draw (chart)` before to set isReady = true?

Comment: draw(chart) if from child component and isReady is setting in parent component and sending to child.

Comment: Forget all the is ready garbage. Just use view child and make sure to not call draw in your component till the after view init hook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in angular specifically you can use `ViewChild` instead of getElementById to get canvas

in angular 7 specifically it will work as follow

[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-viewchild-canvas?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdraw%2Fdraw.component.ts)

component.html

```
<canvas #chart></canvas>
```

component.ts

```js
    import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-draw',
      templateUrl: './draw.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./draw.component.css']
    })
    export class DrawComponent implements OnInit {

      @ViewChild('chart')
      chartElementRef: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>;

      @Input()
      input: any;

      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.draw();
      }

      private draw () { 
        const canvas = this.chartElementRef.nativeElement;
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      }
    }
```

Comment: This will fail. View children aren’t available till the after view init hook

Comment: @bryan60 not true, in my example canvas itself not under ngIf, so ViewChild will set it before ngOnInit

Comment: this is a less common circumstance where it works... best practice is not accessing ViewChild(ren) until the AfterViewInit hook. That's when it's guaranteed: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild#description and here: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#afterview

Comment: this also only even working cause your blitz is angular 7 which only provided static queries. 8+ defaults to dynamic queries and would require you to explicitly set static to true..  i don't see why you'd code in a way that can break with upgrades when you can just use the afterViewinit hook

Comment: @bryan60 it works because `canvas` not angular component and not in component lifecycle, it is intended to how it used. some one try to claim it as a bug but angular team add `static` property instead https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21800#issuecomment-360799520

Comment: that’s one of three reasons. Another is because prior to angular 8, View child queries were static, and the thirs reason is because this happens to not be in an embedded view like an ngIf or ngFor. Queries are now dynamic by default which is why this code is broken in angular versions past 7. But since angular 2, For all these reasons, the best practice has been to wait until after view init to access all view children as that’s when theyre guaranteed. Again. I don’t know why you’d voluntarily write or advocate code that is broken in current angular versions.

Comment: This is 100% unintended usage and the docs back up that you should NOT do this. Advocating it as intended is objectively wrong and misguided. Even the guarantee of static queries in non embedded views being available is subject to change in future versions.

Comment: Thanks @Radik. I tried to implement viewChild logic as per your suggestion but it didn't work. I created an extended stackblitz , "https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-viewchild-canvas-example?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html"  to draw charts per tab.  chart  data will be pulled from a service. i created a dummy service to reproduce the scenarios but it is not working. plz help.

Comment: @usersam you try get data from the resul.x but result is array, example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-viewchild-canvas-example-cayllb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdraw%2Fdraw.component.ts

Comment: @usersam you can suppress error for tests as follow https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-viewchild-canvas-example-cayllb?file=src%2Fapp%2Flist.service.ts or even replace getPosts() with empty result like `of<IPosts[]>()`

Comment: @Radik Thanks.The error "Cannot read property 'getContext' of null" is gone now and it is working. The only problem is,when i click on Purchase tab. is displays north and south children tabs but does not display charts. then i click on north tab (even multiple times) > nothing happens, click on south > displays south chart, click on north=> now north chart displays. and now all tabs work fine..it is strange behavior.

Comment: @usersam did you save it somewhere?

Comment: @Radik. i fixed it by calling getdata function again. but the firstab is still not marked active that default blue underline does not come. This problem is also present in the stackblitz you shared. "https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-viewchild-canvas-example-cayllb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdraw%2Fdraw.component.ts". I am anyway accepting answer as it solved my issue. Thanks you very much :-)

Comment: @Radik , noticed one thing. When dataset is large(in thousands) chart rendering becomes very slow. First time loading can be accepted but when switches among children tabs (north,south..), on every tab click , it calls draw() function. from child component. I wish that lazy loading happens in background.

Comment: @usersam you need Virtual scrolling https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview make another question if it didn help